# I want to create a nav list in the base bundle. How can I allow other bundles to add to that list?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I want to create a navigation list in one of my bundle (the "base" bundle) that will include a couple of options. How can I allow other bundles to add to that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like a more detailed question but here it goes anyway.

First, check [KnpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) for bundles that already provide menu features. Something like [KnpMenuBundle](http://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle). Looks good? Fine, use it.

Nothing fits your taste? Then roll your own. I would go with something like this:

1. Create a `NavListManager` class in the base bundle and a `AbstractNavList` class to be extended by every other bundle that adds options to the navigation list.
2. Each bundle should provide a `NavList` class extending `AbstractNavList`. Theses classes should provide navigation list options.
3. In your base bundle edit the `DependencyInjection\<MyBundle>Extension::load()` method to lookup a `NavList` class in each of your bundles using `$container->getParameter('kernel.bundles')`. Include every collected class in `NavListManager`.
4. Now call something like `$navman->render()` in the template to generate the navigation list.